# should I design a simplified version of a use case and implement it, or should I stick to the exact use case while designing?

Tags: design, agile, requirements

I know that user stories and use cases are written by a customer not the development team alone. And I know that on each iteration the development team picks a number of requested use cases and delivers them by the end of the sprint.

**First question is: Should the requirements analysis and design phase on each iteration be aimed to target the exact given use case at the first place?**

Let's say that we, as the development team, are given a use case to develop like this:

> " Jimmy, as the bank owner, should be able to see the charts showing how much profits has changed on each day during the last week."

As a developer I feel more comfortable to first design and impalement a feature which helps the user to see information in textual form:

> Jimmy, as the bank owner , should be able to see some texts showing how much profit has changed on each day during the last week

after I reach at the point where everything works, start to redesign and change the code so that charts are shown instead of textual info.

If it's okay to first start by focusing on a simplified version of the actual requirement and then move toward the actual requirement gradually, what are those simplified intermediate outcomes called? should they be listed as backlogs?

I know that as an **individual** developer I can do that *gradual* development. But what I want is more, I want to be able to log and track those intermediate stats as pieces of work and be able to assign them to some team member.

So the **second question** is, what should those intermediate states be considered as? are they backlogs? if not, what are they?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking whether it's OK for you to build out the functionality based on text then create the chart before delivering (yes, of course, it's up to you as a developer how to implement the requirements); or whether it's OK for you to unilaterally change the agreed requirements (no, but an option with a smaller scope you could deliver more quickly is absolutely a suggestion you should share and discuss with the product folks in your team)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I want to have those intermediate states be logged and tracked. So that I can assign each to some team member. I'll update my question  to be more precise

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Saying that "user stories and use cases are written by a customer not the development team alone" is an oversimplification. Many user stories and use cases come from the customer and are collaboratively refined with the development team. However, the slicing of the user stories or use cases is usually done almost exclusively by the development team, since they are aware of constraints including technical dependencies and the team's capacity to finish work.

Also, saying that "the development team picks a number of requested use cases and delivers them by the end of the Sprint" is another oversimplification. Depending on your methodology, an iteration should have some level of working software, either suitable for demonstration and use in a test environment or potentially releasable. Use cases capture an entire interaction between an external actor and the system under design. Depending on the complexity of a use case, the development team may not be able to fully implement the use case and all of its flows during one iteration. Even if the team could do so, it may be too risky to complete the use case fully. Completing one path, such as the primary success path, may let the team get feedback and ensure that they have a correct understanding of the use case before introducing more functionality.

Not only is it okay, but common practice, to start with a simplified version of the requirement and iterate toward the requirement. These are often called "slices". Ivar Jacobson uses this term in his definition of [Use Case 2.0](https://www.ivarjacobson.com/publications/white-papers/use-case-ebook), but it's also [used with user stories and other forms of Product Backlog Items in Scrum](https://medium.com/the-liberators/10-powerful-strategies-for-breaking-down-user-stories-in-scrum-with-cheatsheet-2cd9aae7d0eb). Using the terms "slice" and "slicing" should be understood by many practitioners.

How you track this work is up to the team. I would recommend putting this work on the Product Backlog in whatever tool you use and somehow linking them together, so it's clear that a slice relates to a larger unit of work. Doing so, you may find that one slice is part of multiple pieces of work, so you can start to order these slices in a way that lets you open up more possibilities for changing the order of your backlog. Knowing that there is common functionality across multiple use cases or user stories may drive your design and how you implement that functionality.

In the example, I would consider the textual display to be one slice. Perhaps it's closer to how the data is stored or the output of your data analysis routines and can be very easily output. Transforming the data to charts and graphs may require assessing the suitability of different options, introducing a new dependency, learning how to use that dependency, and then integrating the data into it so the data can be visualized. By introducing a textual or tabular format first, you can demonstrate things like security and access control around the data or let your users review the data for correctness based on given inputs. Perhaps you'll even learn that users don't want graphs or maybe want both graphs and the textual output.

Comment: Sincerely Thank you for the great resources you introduced. The article you mentioned breaks the PBIs and that's exactly what I was looking for. But It is mentioning that all the smaller items should again get approved and prioritized by product owner.  I was avoiding to call those slices a backlog, because I was assuming that those slices are not related to the product owner as they are gonna get updated very soon and change into what product owner wants.  Seems nothing is specific to dev team. everything is shared between product owner and developers.